# I have this last exercise in Prolog to solve in lessons i do alone and dont know what to do

Tags: prolog, functor

I have this last problem from the free lessons i take online ,to solve and i dont know from where to start i cant even understand what is this predicate does...

> Write predicate `replace_var_args (Term, Values, NewTerm)` which is true
>   if it replaces the terms of `Term` which are variables by values from
>   the list «Values». That is, the 1st variable of `Term` is replaced by
>   the 1st term of the list `Values`, the 2nd variable of `Term` is
>   replaced by the 2nd term of the list `Values` and so on until the list
>   `Values` becomes empty. Finally, it returns the new term `NewTerm`.
>   Use the built-in predicates like `functor/3`, `=../2`, `var/1`, `nanvar/1`,
>   etc. Examples of goals,
>
> ```
> a) ?- replace_var_args(father(yannis,X), [anna], NewTerm). NewTerm =
> father(yannis,anna),
> b) ?- replace_var_args(f(a,X,g(b), Y,h(a,Z)), [b,c], NewTerm). NewTerm =
> f(a,b,g(b),c,h(a,Z)),
> c) ?- replace_var_args(f(a,X,f(b),Y,h(a,Z)), [b,c,d], NewTerm). NewTerm =
> f(a,b,g(b),c,h(a,d)).
> d) ?- replace_var_args(t(X, Y, Z,a,f(Z,b)), [1,2,3], NewTerm). NewTerm =
> t(1,2,3,a,f(Z,b)).
> ```

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: i cant understand the replacement

Comment: Everything in Prolog is a *term*, so `foo(X, Y)`, for example, is a *term*. And `[a,b]` is a list (also, technically, a *term*). They want you to write a predicate that will do this: `replace_var_args(foo(X, Y), [a,b], NewTerm)` and give you, `NewTerm = foo(a, b)`, which means it substituted, `X = a` and `Y = b`. NOTE that in Prolog variables start with a capital letter, and atoms (non-variable) start lower case. They gave you several other examples. In `replace_var_args(t(X, Y, Z,a,f(Z,b)), [1,2,3], NewTerm). NewTerm =
t(1,2,3,a,f(Z,b)).`, the predicate substituted `X = 1`, `Y = 2`, etc...

Comment: It is interesting to know what shoud happen for example in this case: `?- replace_var_args(foo(X, X), [a, b], New).` Should it fail?